# "have just tried to turn it on" vs "was just trying to turn it on"

Tags: present-perfect, past-continuous

> The TV won’t work. I **have just tried to turn it on**, but I couldn’t.
>
> The TV won’t work. I **was just trying to turn it on**, but I couldn’t.

I'm seeing [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20just%20tried%20to%20turn%2Cwas%20just%20trying%20to%20turn&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3#) Past Continuous is used, not Present Perfect. Could you explain why in that example is preferable Past Continuous? I would use Present Perfect here.

Comment: FWIW, both sound natural to me, and I'm surprised at the low count for present perfect. You get a few hits for it if you remove "turn" from the search, but still very low counts

Comment: It's odd that there are _no_ results for _have just tried..._ Note that some of the results you did get are references to turning a car, turning a person over etc.  rather than switching on a machine.

Comment: I definitely have a preference for the second version, but I'm not sure why.